# "Was dirty" plugin for ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm working on some code that uses a lot of after_save callbacks, and I remember seeing a plugin that allows the `model.changes` array to persist after a call to `save`.

It would be a great help if I could just write `if body_did_change?` in my `after_save` calls, instead of having to hack together something with a `before_save` filter just to set a flag.

I have written something like this myself before, but I'd prefer to use something supported and I swear I've seen this plugin before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is built-in now - a recent feature. I have been using it in my project.. See http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects

Comment: Yeah, I need something that will persist after calling `save` though. As it is now, my `after_save` callbacks don't know which attributes changed prior to the `save` call.

Comment: Wow, my bad. It seems that does actually work in `after_save` calls! The last time I tried this was ~6 months ago and either it's a new addition or I screwed something up earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Way late on your answer here but was searching for the same thing myself...

Rails 3 supports the following:

```
person.name # => 'bob'
person.name = 'robert'
person.save
person.previous_changes # => {'name' => ['bob, 'robert']}
```

See here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Cheers